# redirecting python logging messages with streams

Tags: python, logging, stream, handler, stringio

I want to redirect logging messages to some handling method (e.g. in order so save all messages in a queue). Currently I'm trying to make use of logging.StreamHandler in order to write to a StringIO and then read it somewhere else. In my case this might be a thread continuously reading from the stream but it could also be a callback method being called on every log entry.

```
import threading
import time
import sys
import logging
from StringIO import StringIO

# this thread shall read from a stream 
# continuously and 
def tread_fn( stream ):
    while not stream.eof():       <=== this is not valid but my current approach
        l = stream.readline()
        do_something( l )

stream = StringIO()

handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream)
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel( logging.INFO )

# replace all log handlers
for handler in log.handlers: 
    log.removeHandler(handler)
log.addHandler(handler)

thread = threading.Thread(target = tread_fn, args=[stream])
thread.start()

for i in range(3):        
    time.sleep(1)
    log.error("test")          <=== should be handled line by line
```

I feel like I have overlooked the very obvious and simple best practice but I'm struggling for a while now :)
Maybe I don't need streams at all but currently I'm even failing to write to a stream and reading from it somewhere else..
So in short my questions are:

- how is the main goal achieved the python way?
- how do I write strings to a stream and continuously read from it in another thread?

Comment: One option is to write your own handler that just drops its incoming log records onto a queue. The background thread would then read the records (notice, no serialization needed) one at a time. It kinda depends on what you want to do next, though.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked two questions in one - they should be separate questions. Your main goal can be achieved using e.g. a `QueueHandler`, available in Python 3.2 and later but also available for earlier Python versions through the [`logutils`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/logutils) project.